# Prevent development from TFS build on test failure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, release-management, ms-release-management

I'm working with an existing TFS Build and Release Management setup and know little about the (now deprecated) XAML build system it uses.

In this snippet from the build template below my project is built, tests are ran and then a sequence is started which hands the compiled project over to TFS Release Management for deployment.

```
<Sequence DisplayName="Overall build process">
<mtbac:SetBuildNumber DisplayName="Update build number" BuildNumberFormat="[BuildNumberFormat]" />
<mtbwa:AgentScope DisplayName="Run on agent" MaxExecutionTime="[AgentSettings.GetValue(Of TimeSpan)(&quot;MaxExecutionTime&quot;, new System.TimeSpan(0,0,0))]" MaxWaitTime="[AgentSettings.GetValue(Of TimeSpan)(&quot;MaxWaitTime&quot;, new System.TimeSpan(4,0,0))]" ReservationSpec="[AgentSettings.CreateAgentReservationSpec()]">
  <mtbac:InitializeEnvironment DisplayName="Initialize environment" />
  <mtbat:TfGetSources DisplayName="Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control" CleanWorkspace="[CleanWorkspace]" CreateLabel="[CreateLabel]" VersionOverride="[GetVersion]" />
  <mtba:AssociateChanges DisplayName="Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build" UpdateWorkItems="[UpdateAssociatedWorkItems]" />
  <TryCatch DisplayName="Try" mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="Low">
    <TryCatch.Try>
      <Sequence DisplayName="Compile, Test and Publish">
        <mtba:RunScript DisplayName="Run optional script before MSBuild" FilePath="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PreActionScriptPath&quot;, String.Empty)]" Arguments="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PreActionScriptArguments&quot;, String.Empty)]" />
        <mtba:RunMSBuild DisplayName="Run MSBuild" OutputLocation="[OutputLocation]" CleanBuild="[CleanBuild]" CommandLineArguments="[String.Format(&quot;/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}&quot;, AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;MSBuildArguments&quot;, String.Empty))]" ConfigurationsToBuild="[ConfigurationsToBuild]" ProjectsToBuild="[ProjectsToBuild]" ToolPlatform="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;MSBuildPlatform&quot;, &quot;Auto&quot;)]" RunCodeAnalysis="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;RunCodeAnalysis&quot;, &quot;AsConfigured&quot;)]" />
        <mtba:RunScript DisplayName="Run optional script after MSBuild" FilePath="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PostActionScriptPath&quot;, String.Empty)]" Arguments="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PostActionScriptArguments&quot;, String.Empty)]" />
        <mtba:RunScript DisplayName="Run optional script before Test Runner" FilePath="[AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PreActionScriptPath&quot;, String.Empty)]" Arguments="[AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PreActionScriptArguments&quot;, String.Empty)]" />
        <mtba:RunAgileTestRunner DisplayName="Run VS Test Runner" Enabled="[Not AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of Boolean)(&quot;DisableTests&quot;, false)]" TestSpecs="[AutomatedTests]" ConfigurationsToTest="[ConfigurationsToBuild]" />
        <mtba:RunScript DisplayName="Run optional script after Test Runner" FilePath="[AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PostActionScriptPath&quot;, String.Empty)]" Arguments="[AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;PostActionScriptArguments&quot;, String.Empty)]" />
        <mtba:RunTestImpact DisplayName="Get Impacted Tests" Enabled="[AdvancedTestSettings.GetValue(Of Boolean)(&quot;AnalyzeTestImpact&quot;, true)]" />
        <Sequence DisplayName="Process the release">
          <Sequence.Variables>
            <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="buildDirectory" />
          </Sequence.Variables>
          <mtbwa:GetBuildDirectory DisplayName="Get the Build Directory" Result="[buildDirectory]" />
          <If Condition="[ProcessReleaseTokens]" DisplayName="If ProcessReleaseTokens is set">
            <If.Then>
              <Sequence DisplayName="Initialize tokens">
```

Currently in the event of a test failure the sequence step still executes and the broken build is deployed. I have the "Fail build on test failure" option enabled.

I need to prevent deployments when there are test failures, either by stopping the release step from running or amending the process in release management (I was leaning towards not touching release management at all in the event of a build failure).

Comment: Are you using the release management which is integrated into the TFS?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT it's the previous version with the Visual Studio 2015 client. We plan to upgrade to the new TFS Build vnext in the future but was hoping for a workaround for this in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your build simply spit out the WebDeploy package (e.g. DeployTarget=Package), then have an **InvokeProcess** at the end of the workflow that runs a powershell script to do the actual deployment.

Comment: How would I go about checking if the tests passed? Would I do this at the point of InvokeProcess or within the powershell script?

Comment: For XMAL build, when test failed, the build will still continue. The flag "Fail build on test failure" means when test fails, the build fails. If this flag set to "false", when test fails, the final result will be partly successful.

Comment: Yep I have that flag enabled so my build does fail (as expected) when there is a failing test. Are you saying that InvokeProcess will not be ran in the event of a failed build?

Comment: Another suggestion you could use TFS 2015 Vnext build, you could configure the deploy step after tests to be continue if test step fails.

Comment: Are you saying that InvokeProcess will not be ran in the event of a failed build.?No, the build is still deployed. However it's deployed as a package. I think this can be done in the powershell script. If build passes run the actually deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the XAML definition template to achieve this. Refer to the answer in this question for details: [Release management releasing failed builds also - Triggering release from failed builds](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcce6ce7-830c-4bc2-805b-1cf331e04253/release-management-releasing-failed-builds-also-triggering-release-from-failed-builds?forum=tfsbuild)

Quote it here in case of the link does not work:

> 1. Moved "If ReleaseBuild is Set" activity below "If Not DisableTests".
> 2. Changed Condition of "If ReleaseBuild is Set" to: ReleaseBuild And (treatTestFailureAsBuildFailure = False Or
>      (treatTestFailureAsBuildFailure And (BuildDetail.TestStatus <>
>      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Failed))) And
>      BuildDetail.CompilationStatus <>
>      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildPhaseStatus.Failed
> 3. Inside "If ReleaseBuild is Set" activity's Else part, changed WriteBuildMessage's message to: "Skipped execution because either the
>      ReleaseBuild is not set or some tests have failed or compilation has
>      failed"
> 4. Finally check-in the template and that's it, failed builds wont get deployed.